# Angular fullcalendar show events from a service in angular

Tags: sql, angular, events, fullcalendar

I have implemented fullcalendar in my project. But I can't publish the existing events in my database on the calendar. I am using a service to fetch the events. I know something is missing but I can't figure out what it is. Unfortunately there is not much information about events in fullcalendar angular.

I manage to bring the events in the console, but not publish them in the calendar.

[image]

The code I have used to implement the calendar is in part from one of the github examples. I am using Angular CLI: 10.1.7

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, 
         OnInit, 
         ViewChild, 
         TemplateRef, 
         Input, 
         forwardRef,
         AfterViewChecked,
         ElementRef 
         } from '@angular/core';
//import { MatDialog } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { FullCalendarComponent, 
         CalendarOptions, 
         DateSelectArg, 
         EventClickArg, 
         EventApi,
         EventInput, 
         Calendar,
         formatDate
        } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGrigPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { TimeTableService } from '../../services/timetable.service';
import { Timetable } from '../../models/timetable';
import { global } from '../../services/global';

declare var $: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-calendar',
  templateUrl: './my-calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-calendar.component.css'],
  providers: [TimeTableService]
})

export class MyCalendarComponent implements OnInit {
    public page_title:string;
    public identity;
    public token;
    public timetable: Timetable;
    public status:string;
    public dates;
    public date;
    public url;

public calendarOptions: CalendarOptions;
public eventsModel: any;

@ViewChild('fullcalendar' , { static: true }) calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;
@ViewChild('createEvent', { static: true }) createEvent: TemplateRef<any>;


dateForm: FormGroup;
eventsCalendar: any[] = [];
events: any[] = [];
calendarEvents: EventInput[] = [];
calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, timeGrigPlugin, interactionPlugin];
calendarApi: Calendar;
initialized = false;


constructor(
    private modal: NgbModal,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _timeTableService: TimeTableService,
){
    this.page_title = "Aqui puedes controlar tus citas";
    this.identity = this._therapistService.getIdentity();
    this.timetable = new Timetable(1,'','','','','');
    this.url = global.url;
    this.calendarEvents = [];

}

ngOnInit(): void {
  forwardRef(() => Calendar); 
  this.getTimeTable();
  this.loadEvents();
  

  this.calendarOptions = {
      timeZone: 'local',
      locale:   'es',
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
      headerToolbar: {
        left:   'prev,next today myCustomButton',
        center: 'title',
        right:  'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      buttonText: {
        today:  'Hoy',
        month:  'Mes',
        week:   'Semana',
        day:    'Día',
        list:   'Lista'
      },
      customButtons: {
        myCustomButton: {
          text: 'Crear!',
            //click: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),
            click: function() { 
            $('#crearcita').modal('show');
            }
        }
      },
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      allDaySlot: false,
      defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:45:00',
      forceEventDuration: true,
      weekends: true,
      editable: true,
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      dayMaxEvents: true,

      dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // bind is important! 
      eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
      eventDragStop: this.handleEventDragStop.bind(this),

  };
}
getTimeTable(){
this._timeTableService.getTimeTable().subscribe(
    response => {
        if(response.status == 'success'){
            this.dates = response.dates;
            console.log(this.dates);
            this.dates.forEach(e => {
                let calendarevent = {
                      //startEditable: false,
                      id: e.id,
                      title: e.title,
                      start: new Date(e.date).toISOString(),
                      //allDay: true,
                    };
                console.log(calendarevent);             
                this.eventsCalendar.push(calendarevent);
            });
            this.loadEvents();
        }
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }

);

  }



loadEvents() {

     this.calendarEvents =  this.eventsCalendar;
     console.log(this.eventsCalendar);
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<full-calendar
  *ngIf="calendarOptions"
  #fullcalendar
  [options]="calendarOptions"
  [events]="eventsCalendar"
  (eventClick)="onEventClick($event)"
></full-calendar>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

First I fetch the data from API

```
     this.restApi.getEvents(this.currentDateYear, this.currentDateMonth).subscribe(data  => {
          this.events = data as any;
          this.events =  this.events[0];
```

Then i push the data in a forech into the variable this.eventFromApi

```
 this.events.forEach(element => {
   this.startDate = new Date(element.date.date);
   this.endDate = new Date(this.startDate.getTime() + 
   (element.duration*60*1000));
            this.eventFromApiPush.push({
              title: element.name, 
              start:this.startDate, 
              end: this.endDate,
              extendedProps: {
                id: element.id.toString()
              },
          });
        });
```

Thats my Calender Option in Onint:

```
 this.calendarOptions = {
                headerToolbar: {
                  left: 'prev,next',
                  right: 'dayGridMonth,listMonth'
                },
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                //here i define the events 
                events:this.eventFromApiPush,
                weekends: true,
                eventColor:'blue',
                editable: true,
                selectable: true,
                selectMirror: true,
                dayMaxEvents: true,
                locale: deLocale,
                contentHeight: 500,
                select: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
                eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
                eventsSet: this.handleEvents.bind(this),
                /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
                eventAdd:
                eventChange:
                eventRemove:
                */
              };
        
        
            });
```

Comment: With getTimeTable I get the events from my database. And then I try pushing on calendarEvents. Like I said before I show them on console but I can't show them on the calendar